# Присваивание содержимого ячеек из DataGrid - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Пишу приложение где необходимо по выбору строки в DataGrid присвоить переменным значения ячеек из DataGrid. Сделал перебором switch-case, но не уверен что так валидно и это не костыль.

```
int selectedColumn = 0;
bool selectTrue = false;
private void ListOfNotes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    selectedColumn = ListOfNotes.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    selectTrue = true;
}
```

А вот тут перебираю:

```
private void EditMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (selectTrue)
        {
            NotesWindow notesWindow = new NotesWindow();

            var selectedCell = ListOfNotes.SelectedCells[selectedColumn];
            var cellContent = selectedCell.Column.GetCellContent(selectedCell.Item);
            NotesData notesData = new NotesData();

            for (int i = 0; i < Constants.DATAGRID_SIZE; i++)
            {
                selectedCell = ListOfNotes.SelectedCells[i];
                cellContent = selectedCell.Column.GetCellContent(selectedCell.Item);

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        notesData.Id = Guid.Parse((cellContent as TextBlock).Text);
                        test = notesData.Id;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        notesWindow.header.Text = (cellContent as TextBlock).Text;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        notesWindow.content.AppendText((cellContent as TextBlock).Text);
                        break;
                }
            }
            notesWindow.Show();
        }
        else
            ShowError(UserNotifications.NO_ENTRY_SELECTED);
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        ShowError("Таблица пуста! " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

DataGrid заполняю через сервис WCF

```
  private async void GetNotes()
    {
        try
        {
            //ListOfNotes.ItemsSource = factory.CreateNotesFactory().GetAll();
            using (NoteServiceContractClient notesService1 = new NoteServiceContractClient())
            {
                ListOfNotes.ItemsSource = await notesService1.GetAllAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            ShowError(err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Может есть альтернатива этому решению в виде готовых свойств или методов применимых к DataGrid?

Comment: не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос. Можно привязать `SelectedIndex` и таким образом узнать какой элемент был выбран

Comment: Например в строке 4 ячейки - id, header, content, time. Мне необходимо записать значения из каждой ячейки например в сущность Notes (nt.Id, nt.Header, nt.Content, nt.Time). Сейчас я это делаю бегая по switch;

Comment: В вопросе добавил метод заполнения datagrid

Comment: Внизу ответ дали, пока не закрываю, может кто-нибудь еще интересное решение предложит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте MVVM и Binding.

Модель представления элемента списка:

```
public class ItemVm
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Модель представления окна:

```
public class MyWindowVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemVm> Items { get; }
    public ItemVm SelectedItem { get; set; } // INotifyPropertyChanged

    public MyWindowVm()
    {
        Items = new ...;
        SelectedItem = Items.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratedColumns="false" Items="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Заголовок" Binding="{Binding Header}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Содержимое" Binding="{Binding Content}" />
</DataGrid>
```

В MVVM тут должна быть команда:

```
private void EditMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Используем SelectedItem у MyWindowVm
}
```

Comment: Items = new ...; А что тут? Что в конструкторе?

Comment: @JDo, Заполнение перечня элементов. Я не знаю, откуда вы данные берете.

Comment: Из сервиса, метод возвращает объект сущности.

Comment: @JDo, не важно. Вам нужно заполнить эту коллекцию. По идее, она должна заполняться там же, где сейчас происходит присваивание ListOfNotes.Items.
ItemVm может, например, агрегировать ваши сущности.

Comment: Бегу пробовать! Спасибо за оперативный ответ!

Comment: @JDo. Еще кое-что. Коллекцию лучше создать один раз в конструкторе, а потом заполнять/очищать. Это позволит не волноваться о привязке. Ну или бросать PropertyChanged при изменении свойства-коллекции.